# Can't get Jackson filtering to work

Tags: java, json, lombok, jackson2

Using Jackson Filters for the first time I was very surprised to see it not working at all. Here's the test code that I just wrote:

```
@Test
public void testJsonSerialization() throws JsonProcessingException {
    Principal princi = Principal.builder().fullName("John Smith").role(Role.USER).build().setAccountType(CHILD)
        .setClassAttended(Classes.C10);

    SimpleBeanPropertyFilter filter = SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept("fullName");
    FilterProvider provider = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("bareBonesFilter", filter);
    JsonFilter jFilter = Principal.class.getAnnotation(JsonFilter.class);
    assertNotNull(jFilter); // passes
    assertEquals("bareBonesFilter", jFilter.value()); // passes
    provider.findPropertyFilter("bareBonesFilter", princi); // doesn't throw exception, therefore a filter was found

    ObjectWriter writer = (new ObjectMapper()).setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_ABSENT)
        .enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT).writer(provider);
    String json = writer.writeValueAsString(princi);
    assertFalse(json.contains("accountType")); //this fails
}
```

Using Jackson 2.7.1.

What am I missing? Do I need to add some special configuration somewhere to enable use of filters?

### Update 1

I tried the above code with 2.7.9 and 2.9.4 as suggested by @StaxMan, and neither one worked.

Then instead of using the `Principal` class (which has grown large & complex), I tried the above code with a simpler `SgEmailInfo` class (which is just a data holder) and the filtering worked as expected!

```
@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
@JsonFilter("bareBonesFilter")
public class SgEmailInfo {

    private long created;

    private String email;

    private String reason;

    private String status;

}
```

[`@Data`](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data) and [`@Accessors`](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Accessors) are [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) annotations for auto-generating some code. The `Principal` class also uses these annotations but also other Lombok annotations:

```
@Entity //Objectify annotation
@Cache(expirationSeconds = 600) //Objectify annotation
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id", callSuper = false) // Lombok
@ToString(callSuper = true, doNotUseGetters = true, of = { "id", "firstName", "middleName",
        "lastName", "profileName", "roles" }) // Lombok
@Accessors(chain = true)
@JsonFilter("bareBonesFilter")
public class Principal extends AccountEntity<Principal, EmailPrincipal>
        implements Serializable, ProfileShort, ProfileMedium
```

I am also using `@JsonIgnore` annotation on many of the properties and getters of `Principal`.

There's also the [`@Builder`](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder) annotation on a constructor of `Principal`:

```
@Builder
private Principal(String fullName, @Singular List<Role> roles)
```

Could any of these annotations or code generated by Lombok be interfering with the filtering?

Comment: Very first thing is to use a more modern version. Of 2.7, there are many, many patches (2.7.9), and the most recent in general is 2.9.4.

Comment: Yes, Lombok is... bit of a PITA since it augments annotations in a way that may not play nice with other libs (or at least are not immediately visible).

Answer (score 0):

Code seems legit to me. After trying out with a more recent version (to ensure it wasn't a bug that has since been fixed), could you file a bug against `jackson-databind`? It is possible I am missing some problem with above code, but it is nothing superbly obvious, so there's a chance it could be a bug.

Comment: I tried with 2.7.9 & 2.9.4, but the `Principal` class' properties wouldn't get filtered correctly. A simpler `SgEmailInfo` class filters properly. See **Update 1** above.

Comment: I suspect Lombok is involved, but do not know exactly how: it more commonly causes issues with creation during deserialization. If a test case with replacing of Lombok constructs with equivalent (of what it adds implicitly to bytecode) could reproduce problem, filing an issue would make sense.

Comment: The presence of `JsonIgnore` shouldn't make any difference to filtering?

Comment: @markvgti It should; anything `@JsonIgnore`s should be ignored altogether and not presented to filter. It is static setting that basically removes property (or access to it, anyway, and adds to "known and ignorable" set in case of deserialization).